# RegExp not working with the Validation Form in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

This is a part of a project regarding feedback forms.

I already manage to create the validation form properly thanks to the answers here in StackOverflow developers.

But the problem is creating this regular expression which seems to not work on the validation form. I found in flutter docs the Iterable but I do not know how can I implement it on the dart page.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  final title;
  const SimpleDialog(this.title, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Alert'),
      content: Text(title),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: const Text('OK'))
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FeedbackPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedbackPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FeedbackPage> createState() => _FeedbackPageState();
}

class _FeedbackPageState extends State<FeedbackPage> {
  final nameOfuser = TextEditingController();
  final emailOfuser = TextEditingController();
  final messageOfuser = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<bool> isTypeSelected = [false, false, false, true, true];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // AppBar para sa taas ng design
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            "PicLeaf",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          shadowColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 95, 94, 94),
        ),

        //body of the application
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffeeeeee),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              const Text(
                "Feedback",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                    fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0)),
              ),
              const Text(
                "Give us your feedback!",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: nameOfuser,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          hintText: "Name",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        validator: (nameOfuser) {
                          if (nameOfuser == null || nameOfuser.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your Name';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: emailOfuser,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          hintText: "Email",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        validator: (emailOfuser) {
                          if (emailOfuser == null || emailOfuser.isEmpty) {
                            String emailOfuser1 = emailOfuser.toString();
                            String pattern = r'\w+@\w+\.\w+';
                            if (RegExp(pattern).hasMatch(emailOfuser1)) {
                              return 'Please enter your Email Properly';
                            } else {
                              return 'Please enter your Email';
                            }
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: messageOfuser,
                        maxLines: 6,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          hintText: "Message",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        validator: (messageOfuser) {
                          if (messageOfuser == null || messageOfuser.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your Message';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      MaterialButton(
                        height: 50.0,
                        minWidth: double.infinity,
                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return const SimpleDialog(
                                      'Feedback Submitted');
                                });
                            Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                              "Name": nameOfuser.text,
                              "Email": emailOfuser.text,
                              "Message": messageOfuser.text,
                              "Time": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                            };
                            setState(() {
                              nameOfuser.clear();
                              emailOfuser.clear();
                              messageOfuser.clear();
                            });
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection("FeedbackMessages")
                                .add(data);
                          }
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          "SUBMIT",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 10),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Contact Us!',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0)),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                            child: TextButton.icon(
                              // <-- TextButton
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.facebook,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 35.0,
                              ),
                              label: const Text(
                                'facebook.com/picleaf',
                                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium'),
                              ),
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                              child: TextButton.icon(
                                // <-- TextButton
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.email,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  size: 35.0,
                                ),

                                label: const Text(
                                  'picleaf@gmail.com',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium'),
                                ),

                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: `String pattern = r'\w+@\w+\.\w+';`... Uh, no. No, please don't use this regex to validate email.  It's wrong.  The shortest regex to validate an RFC822 email address is about 2400 characters, and is given in https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.  Anything shorter is WRONG, unless you're using a grammar, as package:email_validator properly does.  Use that for Dart/Flutter please.

Comment: wait I am new to the regular expressions and I found out that there is RFC5322 or should I download a pub dev with a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this validator:

```
validator: (emailOfuser) {
    if (emailOfuser == null || emailOfuser.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter your Email';
    } else if (emailOfuser.isNotEmpty) {
        String emailOfuser1 = emailOfuser.toString();
        String pattern = r'\w+@\w+\.\w+';
        if (RegExp(pattern).hasMatch(emailOfuser1) == false) {
             return 'Please enter your Email Properly';
        }
    }
    return null;
},
```

Comment: You can also use https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator package too

Answer (score 0):

try to implement like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EmailValidationForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const EmailValidationForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EmailValidationForm> createState() => _EmailValidationFormState();
}

class _EmailValidationFormState extends State<EmailValidationForm> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Email Validation'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              autofocus: false,
              maxLength: 300,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              autocorrect: false,
              validator: (email) {
                if (email!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'required field';
                } else if (email.trim().contains(' ')) {
                  return 'contain space';
                } else if (!emailValid(email)) {
                  return 'invalid email';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (email) {
                return debugPrint(email);
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    formKey.currentState!.save();
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Validate')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

bool emailValid(String email) {
  final RegExp regex = RegExp(
      r"^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\']+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\']+)*)|(\'.+\'))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$");
  return regex.hasMatch(email.trim());
}
```

Comment: just a confirmation is the bool emailValid is in a class?

Comment: No, please don't use this regex to validate email.  It's wrong.  The shortest regex to validate an RFC822 email address is about 2400 characters, and is given in https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.  Anything shorter is WRONG, unless you're using a grammar, as package:email_validator properly does.  Use that for Dart/Flutter please.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz is RFC 5322 be better I found in another regex question in stackoverflow that RFC 5322 is better at filtering emails?